# Static linking sfml errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml, static-linking

I've been trying to statically link sfml to a c++ project, but It always gives me compiler errors, does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it;

[image: Compiler Errors]

**edit:**

This is the code that produced the error:

[image]

and this is what I've put into the Linker/include/additional dependencies section:

[image]

I hope that's all you need, but if there's anything else, please be specific (I'm new to this)

**edit 2:**
Here are all the errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_std_error referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)    Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_CreateCompress referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)   Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_destroy_compress referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z) Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_stdio_dest referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)   Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_defaults referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z) Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_quality referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)  Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_compress referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)   Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_write_scanlines referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)  Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_finish_compress referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::vector > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)  Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj)    1
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK1120 9 unresolved externals  Dungeon3.0  C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Debug\Dungeon3.0.exe 1

Comment: Please [edit] to give textual information in textual form.

Comment: What did you do to link that library? Please show an equivalent command line, e.g. with gcc, along with a small program which has the same error. This would make a [mcve] which your question is otherwise lacking.

Comment: Iv'e updated it with images for those things you asked for

Comment: Yes, more images of text. Please read the feedback your are given on a question. Show text as text, please.

Comment: You mean the Error messages;

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_std_error referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::priv::ImageLoader::writeJpg(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?writeJpg@ImageLoader@priv@sf@@AAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@5@II@Z)

Comment: Dungeon3.0 C:\Users\hhgra\source\repos\Dungeon3.0\Dungeon3.0\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(ImageLoader.cpp.obj) 1

Comment: That's one (it was too long so i hade to put it across multiple comments)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. It allows for much more space.

Comment: but that's what you wanted?

Comment: I added all the error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're using an outdated version of SFML that still relies on libjpeg, which you didn't link (since it's no longer required in newer versions).

Ideally, download the latest source from the [official repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) and compile it using CMake, which will give you compatible and up to date files.